# How to add text in front of IconButton

Tags: reactjs, icons, material-ui

I need to add custom text before my `IconButton` of material ui. Below is the code of button

```
 <div className={classes.toolbar}>     
 <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
        {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
 </IconButton>
 </div>
```

How to add a text before icon?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a the Button component and style it accordingly

```
<Button
  variant="contained"
  color="secondary"
  className={classes.button}
>
  My Button Text
  {
    theme.direction === 'rtl'
    ? <ChevronRightIcon />
    : <ChevronLeftIcon />
  }
</Button>
```